# PHP timestamp illegal values

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I'm working on a Chat Room program and I want to have the time that a message was submitted to be recorded and shown, but I'm having problems (otherwise I wouldn't be here). The program records the date/time with the table as following:

```
  $table_str = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$ChatTable`
    (
      `username`              VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
      `message`               VARCHAR(280) NOT NULL,
      `updated_at`            TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0,
      `posted_at`             DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
    )";
```

When a message is submitted, it is supposed to record the current date/time when it was posted, and then later it is selected from the table, but my problem is the fact that it somehow records an illegal value and shows the data as: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 Even though I can get the date/time to display without much difficulty using the commented out part in the td id= time, but it only displays the current time and doesn't store it. Any help, please? I've search the web for an answer and haven't found a solution.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $ChatTable");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>User</th>
<th>Message</th>
<th>Time Posted</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td id='usersty'>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td id='messagesty'>" . $row['message'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td id= 'time'>" . /*gmdate('l F \ jS, Y h:i:s A')*/$row['posted_at'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

This is where the information is inserted:

```
  $posted_at= mysqli_query(date('YY-MM-DD','HH:MM:SS'));

  $sql= "INSERT INTO $ChatTable ( username, message, posted_at )
            VALUES ( '$username', '$_POST[$message]', '$_POST[posted_at]')";


    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }
```

Comment: We'll need to see the code where you insert something in the chat.

Comment: Are you using PHP to set the `posted_at` value in the database record, otherwise it defaults to NULL according to your table definition

Comment: what are you stuffing into the field? mysql requires dates/datetimes to be in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format. Anything else is highly likely to trigger the all-zeroes data.

Comment: Also, why are "updated_at" and "posted_at" nullable columns? Can a post that has never been posted or updated exist? Why do they have default values? Would it make sense for any one post to keep those defaults?

Comment: Why not use `posted_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and let the database record it for you

Comment: Correction: `updated_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

Comment: Don't inject $_POST values directly into your database

Comment: $posted_at= mysqli_query(date('YY-MM-DD','HH:MM:SS'));

Comment: Also, thanks for the help everyone of you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line:

```
$posted_at= mysqli_query(date('YY-MM-DD','HH:MM:SS'));
```

There are multiple issues with it:

1. You're using `mysqli_query()` when you probably mean `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. But you don't need to escape that value since it does not contain any characters that can break your query.
2. You're using `date()` incorrectly. The first parameter is the format of the string it will produce, the second is an optional Unix Timestamp which we don't use here.
3. The format for your date string is also wrong. See the [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) page for how to properly format the date string.

Here is your corrected code:

```
$posted_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

An alternative to this is to just set this value in your query which is cleaner and faster:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO $ChatTable ( username, message, posted_at )
        VALUES ( '$username', '$_POST[$message]', NOW())";
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed my problem! I cannot express enough gratitude!

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems wrong, here's how you interpolate array values:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO $ChatTable ( username, message, posted_at )
            VALUES ( '$username', '{$_POST[$message]}', '{$_POST['posted_at']}')";
```

Note: Not that this is the best way build a query but maybe it's enough for your purposes.